# what does $this mean within a class definition?

Tags: php, oop, class, this

As I continue to try and improve myself as a junior PHP developer, I have started to try break down other peoples work. I find it helps me understand, as well as giving me ideas.

Two things I do not get, in a PHP class, what $this means, and what array($this,'some_function') means when I would expect a function name in it's place.

Many thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because both questions have been answered before (see dupes in my answers)

Comment: It's not off topic, it's a duplicate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please see the [PHP Manual on Classes and Objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php). `$this` refers to the object instance. Also see these questions:

- [What does the variable $this mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523479/what-does-the-variable-this-mean-in-php)
- [What is the meaning of $this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696874/what-is-the-meaning-of-this)

For `array($this,'some_function')` see the [PHP manual on callbacks](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback). In methods and functions that do accept callbacks, like `call_user_func`, it means call the method `some_function` on `$this`. See

- [How do I implement a callback in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48947/how-do-i-implement-a-callback-in-php)
- [What is a callback function and how do I use it with OOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231327/what-is-a-callback-function-and-how-do-i-use-it-with-oop)

*Marking this as CW because it's not meant as an answer but the reason for closevoting as duplicate*

Comment: why would we use this syntax, and not $this->some_function()?

Comment: @Mild because `$this->some_function()` would execute the function, while `array($this, 'some_function')` does not and thus allows passing the function around for defered calling.

Answer (score 1):

`$this` is a class pointer. `$this` in class give access to class properties and methods.