# $this vs function name

Tags: php, oop, this, keyword

I am getting a hang of OOP and finally started creating them in my scripts. One thing I don't get it is the "$this" after creating an instance of class. For example, this guy coded:

```
class Form
{
protected $inputs = array();    

public function addInput($type, $name)
{
     $this->inputs[] = array("type" => $type,
            "name" => $name);
}


}

 $form = new form();

 $this->addInput("text", "username");
 $this->addInput("text", "password");
```

Notice that the last two lines show that he used $this->addInput().

How is it different from $form->addInput? I always used the name of variable I use to create an instance of class. I don't see what $this->function() does. How does the PHP know which object it's referring to?

From what I understand, $this->var is used in any methods within that object. If there's no $this->var but rather plain $variable then it cannot be used in other methods other than the method that has that $variable, correct?

related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035449/why-is-oop-hard-for-me/3689613#3689613

Comment: Um, I think that code is wrong. It should defiantly be `$form->` not `$this->` for the last 2 lines.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what does $this mean within a class definition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776696/what-does-this-mean-within-a-class-definition)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Incorrect
$this->addInput("text", "username");
$this->addInput("text", "password");
```

This code is incorrect. There is no `$this` when you're not in a class method. That should be `$form`. So to answer your question: the difference is that `$form->addInput` is correct and `$this->addInput` is invalid!

```
// Correct
$form->addInput("text", "username");
$form->addInput("text", "password");
```

It looks like you understand OOP better than the person who wrote this code. You're drinking from a tainted well. Yikes!

Comment: I just copied the code in PHP file and it did generate an error! I guess I'll have to correct that posting.